# SVG image tag with title

Tags: image, svg, tags

Is there any chance I can add a title attribute to an image tag in SVG that on hovering on that image I'll get a tooltip ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Please share.

Comment: See the following link http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StyleElementTitleAttribute

Answer (score 2):

[w3.org:TitleAndDescriptionElements](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/struct.html#TitleAndDescriptionElements) plus [example](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/examples/title-desc-tooltip.svg)
[SVG Title (tooltip)](http://www.mecxpert.de/svg/tooltips.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tag `<title>Tooltip text</title>` inside your `<image>` tag.